# Does a graphics card affect video playback?

Tags: video, graphics-card, cpu, vlc-media-player

I'm looking at buying a new laptop, primarily for playing movies with VLC, browsing, using Microsoft Office, and a bit of coding.

The trouble I had with my old laptop, (a dual core celeron running windows 8), was that it couldn't handle running 10GB movie files in VLC.

What I'm wondering, when buying a new laptop, whether I should just go for a high-end processor, or go for a lower end processor with a good graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

A Video card does affect video playback... but, your issues were probably more down to CPU and drive I/O.

If you had a 10Gb file, I am guessing it was most likely 4k or uncompressed 1080P (or compressed/high bit rate).

A Celeron is typically a low end processor, and with low end processors come low end 5400 RPM (or god help you, 4800 RPM) hard drives, which would also be a problem.

Quite frankly, it is too hard to diagnose exactly which was the limiting factor, but, none of them make for good quality video playback.

However, modern Intel HD graphics which is pretty standard on all machines (even low end ones), is pretty damn decent now and you most likely wouldn't need a dedicated graphics card.

... That being said, try going for at least something 3rd gen or above for good performance that will last a good few years.